# Send Data with jquery to node application

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I am new to node/express js and have a simple app which provides an index.html

in that html this gives me a 404 not found error

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url + "/json/addData'",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       data: {"app" : JSON.stringify("ID=10")},
       cache: false,
       success: function (result) { console.log(result); }
});
```

but this works fine

```
http://localhost:8081/api/json/addData?id=10
```

to this function running in the express app instance

```
app.get('/api/json/addData/', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.query.id);
   res.send("Success");
});
```

when changing the function to app.post I still get a 404.
when changing the ajax to get I again get a 404 error

what would be the correct way to post a javascript object (or it's values) to a node app and how to recieve it ?

sorry for the noob questions. All searching brought so far no working result for me

Comment: Which version of express are you using? I found this related to express 4: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/handle-get-post-request-express-4/ . It seems you need some extra work to get app.post() to work. However I didn't try the solution, but maybe it helps. GL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post the correct api url and send the correct parameter as a query in data with param being id and value being 10.

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "http://localhost:8080/api/json/addData'",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       data: {"id" : "10"},
       cache: false,
       success: function (result) { console.log(result); }
});
```

You need a middleware to parse the params in app.post. That being a body-parser

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Use

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies

app.post('/api/json/addData/', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.query.id);
   res.send("Success");
});
```

Comment: thanks but that can't be all. The express app function has still app.get, so I get still 404. How to correctly recieve the json data ?

Comment: thanks for the edit, I tried that but now I get complains about the missing middleware json...another issue. I will agree your solution once fixed and checked..thanks

Comment: after installing now everything on the node side. I get bad request from your ajax example. Any Idea why ?

Comment: Because you are requesting JSON and sending back text. Send back JSON from NODEjs server. Try console logging into the NODEjs post function nd see if request is coming there as well or not

Comment: sorry took to long to try again and vote your answer up

Comment: But you accepted this answer long ago right. I though you were able to solve the issue

Comment: yes it's all fine now thanks. just takes time for me looking back here...also the app changed a lot. thanks